# Create Calendar Table in Snowflake with Dynamic Date Ranges

Tags: calendar, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I want to create Calendar Table in Snowflake which has start and end date as dynamic dates.

Start Date & End Date should be Min & Max dates of Sales Fact Table.

Can anybody help how can we pass dynamic dates in snowflake View/Table.

Comment: Just out of interest, why would you want to? Why not just create a calendar table with a start date far enough in the past and and end date far enough in the future?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following query to generate a date table, with some extra columns which you may want for data manipulation.

```
select dateadd(day,seq,dt::date) dat ,  year(dat) as "YEAR", quarter(dat) as "QUARTER OF YEAR",
       month(dat) as "MONTH", day(dat) as "DAY", dayofmonth(dat) as "DAY OF MONTH",
       dayofweek(dat) as "DAY OF WEEK",dayname(dat) as dayName,
       dayofyear(dat) as "DAY OF YEAR"
from (
select seq4() as seq,  dateadd(month, 1, '1980-01-01'::date) dt from table(generator(rowcount => 16000))
);
```

Comment: be careful with seq4() it does not guarantee a sequential 1-n sequence. it just guarantees an increasing sequence, so it's helpful to use a row_number() in addition to make sure you aren't skipping dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator function to create the number of records that you need, then use a ROW_NUMBER() to make sure that it's producing a sequential list of numbers. With that you can easily add that sequence of numbers to your start date.

In this example `$numdays` needs to be variable because the generator function only takes constants. That makes it a little trickier to use as in a view (you can use session variables in a view, but then the view will only work in a session where you've created that variable), but you could definitely use this output to create a table, and run that regularly in a stored procedure.

```sql
set startdate = (select min(date(SALE_TIMESTAMP)) from fact_sales);
set numdays = (select datediff(DAY, min(date(SALE_TIMESTAMP)), max(date(SALE_TIMESTAMP))) from fact_sales);

SELECT DATEADD(DAY, c.n, $startdate) AS MY_DATE
FROM(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1) - 1 FROM TABLE(generator(rowcount=>$numdays))) c(n);
```

Here's a workaround that would allow you to create this in a view.
The main concession here is using an arbitrary value for the number of values that the generator can create (note the `generator(rowcount=>10000)`). You can set this value high enough that it's very unlikely that you'll run out of dates, and it'll still be performant.

```sql
SELECT 
    DATEADD(DAY, c.n, (SELECT date(min(SALE_TIMESTAMP)) FROM fact_sales)) AS MY_DATE
FROM(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1) - 1 FROM TABLE(generator(rowcount=>10000))) c(n)
WHERE MY_DATE <= (SELECT date(max(SALE_TIMESTAMP)) FROM fact_sales);
```

Comment: here's another workaround for the constant in the generator function (still requires running an extra query though)
https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-get-passed-NOT-A-CONSTANT-error-while-using-GENERATOR-function

Comment: I do agree with the other responses that it seems odd to want a date table that is restricted to the dates in your fact table. It's often easier to just build out a table that has all of your dates and then some, off into the future.

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to accept answers that are helpful, for future reference :)